# ansible 2.0.0.2 - shutil.rmtree error but the playbook success

Tags: python, jenkins, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

Im running with Ansible 2.0.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. My playbooks run fine on ansible 1.9 but I get the following error at the end of my playbook run.

```
PLAY RECAP 
*********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=62   changed=13   unreachable=0    failed=0   
clientnode.com             : ok=12   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0   

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 124, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(C.DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP, True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

So the playbook is success but the Jenkins job fails because of this python error.
How can I solve

Comment: Seems like you have conflicting Ansible packages or broken installation: `/usr/bin/ansible-...` scripts of Ansible 2, but python packages of Ansible 1.9.

Comment: thank you.
How can I take the python version to the same?
I run a /usr/bin/ansible --version and get the same error.

Comment: Not "python version", but "ansible python package version". It depends on how did you install it. I suggest to delete all existing Ansible installations and install it via `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following  command

```
sudo pip install ansible==2.1.1.0
```

The apt installed package was 2.1.1.0 therefore the pip version should increase to the same.

Comment: You should not have apt and pip packages simultaneously! You may hit all kind of weird behaviour with this setup. Delete all and install only one package.